# HttpPost a list of new/modified items and merge the new id`s on client side

Tags: web-services, rest, http, asp.net-core

I am doing a Http Post request to the server sending a list of items.

These items are either new or modified. I will clarify that on the backend and accordingly add or attach those items to my database context.

The user interface remains during that save changes operation. I do not do any redirect.

When the server side save changes is done there where e.g. 5 new items were added to the database I want to add those 5 new database id`s to the client side objects.

How can I do this?

What I do is not very REST like... If I would do 5 separated http post call then I could easily assign the new database id to the sent item.

I do not want many https calls and this 5 items need to be changed in a transactional way on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your controller that takes an array of multiple items. It would look something like

```
    public void CreateABunch([FromBody] List<Item> Items)
    {
        databaseContext.AddRange(Items);
        databaseContext.SaveChanges()
    }
```

Comment: I did not ask how to pass a collection of items to the server.